# Each saddle point is a isolated critical point?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

**Proposition**: each saddle point is a isolated critical point.

I can not find a counterexample to disprove it, I think it is false.

Some idea?

Comment: Context, please?  What are your assumptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)(x-y)^3.$ Then $f$ has a saddle point at each point on the line $y=x.$ Proof: A simple computation shows $f$ has a critical point at each point on this line. Since $f(x,0) = x^5,$ $f$ has no local extremum at $(0,0),$ hence $(0,0)$ is a saddle point. At any $(a,a)$ with $a\ne 0,$ you can check that $f$ changes sign as you move along the circle of radius $\sqrt 2 a.$  Thus every $(a,a)$ is a saddle point for $f.$

Answer (score 1):

For example, try $f(x,y) = x^8 (2+\sin(1/x^2)) - y^2$ for $x \ne 0$ with $f(0,y) = -y^2$.